# MySQL table doesn't exist after updating CHARACTER SET

Tags: mysql

After converting the character set from `utf8` to `utf8mb4` on one of my tables, the change works as expected until the MySQL server is restarted. After the restart, I get `[42S02][1146] Table 'db.myTable' doesn't exist`

This has happened every time I have attempted to update the character sets. This is the change that I have been running:

```sql
LOCK TABLES myTable WRITE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE myTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Where am I going wrong? When converting character sets, is there something else I should be doing? and is there any possible way to recover from this without having to restore a backup?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out where I went wrong.

Running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` showed that a FOREIGN KEY was causing the issue as the other table had a different CHAR SET.

Changing the CHAR SET of all my tables has now resolved my problem.